# How to test swiping between Activities in Espresso?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am creating a test in Espresso that calls `swipeRight()` to go to the `MainActivity` where behavior is set before returning to `ConsumerSettingsActivity` to test `Views`. However, the issue is that after calling the swipe, I get a `NoActivityResumedException` that points to the second tested line with `R.id.mode_text`.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ConsumerSettingsActivityTest {

private ConsumerSettingsActivity mConsumerSettingsActivity;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<ConsumerSettingsActivity> mActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(ConsumerSettingsActivity.class);

@Before
public void initialize() {
    mConsumerSettingsActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
}

@Test
public void checkCorrectButtonsAreClickableInPhotoModeThenReturnToMainActivity() {

    // swipe to MainActivity and set behavior
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.settings_top_bar), isDisplayed())).perform(swipeRight());
    onView(withId(R.id.mode_text)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.photo_mode)).perform(click());


    // test ratio Views
    onView(withId(R.id.ratio_full)).check(matches(isClickable()));
    onView(withId(R.id.ratio_full)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.ratio_square)).check(matches(isClickable()));
    onView(withId(R.id.ratio_square)).perform(click()); 
...
}
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem. This happen to me when the screen on my device was off. Is the screen of your device on? And I also have to wait 500ms after each swipe to wait until the swipe is done. Hope it helps.

Comment: The device screen is always on and unlocked. Once I call swipe, a button that does the same thing is pressed and the error occurs. I tried adding a `Thread.sleep(1500)` after the first swipe, but receive `RuntimeException: : No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `MainActivity` was called without being created.

Long answer: When `ConsumerSettingsActivity` called swipe  to change to `MainActivity`, the actual swiping called `finish()`. Since `MainActivity` was not created, a `NoActivityResumedException` was thrown. To solve this, the test was changed to start with `MainActivity`, where it would then swipe to `ConsumerSettingsActivity`. Also, I did not need to make the thread sleep to be able to swipe between Activities.